# Why spread() method doesn't work in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using a `Sequelize` for my `node.js` app. I use `findOrCreate()` method to create a new user if not exist. Accordingly to [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html)  `findOrCreate` returns an array containing the object that was found or created and a boolean that will be true if a new object was created and false if not.

The sequelize recommend to use `spread()` method which divides the array into its 2 parts and passes them as arguments to the callback function. First part is a user object and second is boolean if new row was added.

I work in `async/await` style. My code is:

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            let insertedUser = await User.findOrCreate({
                where: { email: req.body.userEmail },
                defaults: {
                    pass: req.body.userPass
                }
            })
            insertedUser.spread((user, created) => {
                if(created) {
                    res.json(user.email)
                }
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`ERROR! => ${err.name}: ${err.message}`)
            res.status(500).send(err.message)
        }
    }
})
```

After post request I get an error:

```
ERROR! => TypeError: insertedUser.spread is not a function
```

Why is that, the doc says it must be a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`spread` method does not exist on resolved value from `findOrCreate`. You have to either chain `spread` with `then` of `promise` returned by `findOrCreate`. Or you need to chain with `findOrCreate` directly and use `await`.

Here is the updated code with `await`:

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            let created = await User.findOrCreate({
                where: { email: req.body.userEmail },
                defaults: {
                    pass: req.body.userPass
                }
            }).spread((user, created) => {
                return created;
            })
            if(created) {
                res.json(user.email)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`ERROR! => ${err.name}: ${err.message}`)
            res.status(500).send(err.message)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide the second example with await also. Want to understand it with example. Thank you in advance

Comment: Here is a very insightful article: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/callbacks-promises-and-async-await-ad4756e01d90