# Sequelize findOrCreate(...).spread is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using the sequelize 6. When I'm runing `findOrCreate().spread` it says "findOrCreate(...).spread is not a function". Here is my code:

```
const response = await Response.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        participantId,
        questionId,
    },
    defaults: responseNewDetail,
})
    return res.status(200).send({ status: 0, data: response })
```

This is working fine, but it does not seperate the created status and the model value.
When I'm trying to use spread:

```
Response.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        participantId,
        questionId,
    },
    defaults: responseNewDetail,
}).spread(function(response,created){
    return res.status(200).send({ status: 0, data: response })
})
```

It says "Response.findOrCreate(...).spread is not a function".
This is the model file(response.js):

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize")

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
    sequelize.define(
        "Response",
        {
            responseId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
                field: "Response_ID",
                autoIncrement: true,
            },
            companyId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                field: "Company_ID",
            },
...
    )
```

Response model:

```
const ResponseModel = require("../models/response")
const Response = ResponseModel(sequelize, DataTypes)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: In your second example, the one with `.spread()`, are you still using `await Response.findOrCreate`?

Comment: I'm expecting to use await as the first one if I can.But the problem here is the ```.spread()``` is not a function, I want to return the model only instead of include the created status. I'm using the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042399/why-spread-method-doesnt-work-in-sequelize, but not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using await, you can change:

```
const response = await Response.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        participantId,
        questionId,
    },
    defaults: responseNewDetail,
})
    return res.status(200).send({ status: 0, data: response })
```

to

```
const [ response, created ] = await Response.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        participantId,
        questionId,
    },
    defaults: responseNewDetail,
})
    return res.status(200).send({ status: 0, data: response })
```

and all will be well.

This doesn't address the spread not a function thing though. For that, I only noticed this when I upgraded sequelize from an older version (I've been using sequelize since version 1). Your example of spread really should be working but for whatever reason it does not anymore (it doesn't for me either). Typically the only time I'm using spread instead of just awaiting it is when I want to defer execution of something. Right or wrong, I've begun to tackle that by just wrapping the await/async version in:

```
setImmediate(async () => {
    // async things here
});
```

Hope I helped, sorry if I didn't.

Comment: why `response` doesn't return `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

eleborating [Brian's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63949109/14267427) :-

`findOrCreate` returns two values first model instance and second created status,
so you can use

```js
const [model,created] = ModelName.findOrCreate();
```

(Model Response in your case)

to get created status.